# C++ Xcode Undefined symbols for architecture

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, clang

I get an error, when I try to compile my code with Xcode. You can see the error here:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Sun::Datum2JDatum(Sun::Time)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It seems for me, that he doesn't see my Sun-File.
In my opinion, I included everything. But I don't find the problem. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

This is my main.cpp:
I included all libraries that I need plus my Sun.hpp.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "Sun.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    struct tm* timeinfo;
    static char buf[200];
    time_t now = time(NULL);

    timeinfo = localtime(&now);

    Sun::Sun sunposition;
    Sun::Time time;

    // ...

    Sun::JDatum datum = sunposition.Datum2JDatum(time); // Here I got the Error

    return 0;
}
```

Sun.hpp:

```
class Sun{

public:
    typedef struct{
        double jd;
        double jd0;
        double T;
        double T0;
    } JDatum;

    Coordinates Locationdetermination(Sun::JDatum, Sun::Location);
    JDatum Datum2JDatum(Sun::Time);
};
```

Sun.cpp:

Also in Sun.cpp is the Sun.hpp included.

```
#include "Sun.hpp"

using namespace std;

Sun::JDatum Datum2JDatum(Sun::Time Now){
    //...
}
```

I can't find actually the mistake. It would be nice, if you would help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Is `Sun.cpp` in `Project -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sun.cpp change to:

```
JDatum Sun::Datum2JDatum(Sun::Time Now){
    //...
}
```